# The Witness - Keep Tower Puzzle - Why Is This Incorrect?

Tags: the-witness

I'm not sure why this is wrong. Could someone explain it to me?

[image: Keep Tower Incorrect]

Comment: One of the L shapes you've accounted for is backwards.

Comment: @Vemonus how so? all 3 of them would be correct if they can be rotated (the middle one is 180 degrees rotated of the top one, the bottom one 90 degrees counter-clockwise of the middle)

Comment: The top left is correct, but the one directly attached to it. That one is backwards. All of the shapes you're given are backwards Ls, but that one accounts for a forwards L.

Comment: The straight 4 is wrong, see related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255540/the-witness-solution-incorrect?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

The section with the tetris-pieces is incorrect.  That would only work if the straight-piece could be rotated (it can't) or if the backwards-L-shapes could be mirrored (they can't)

Comment: This solution doesn't require mirroring of the L shapes, they are all backwards Ls.

Comment: @Austin: Yes, it does require either mirroring one of the L's, or rotating the straight-piece.  Unless your point was just to be pedantic about the piece-names, in which case, I'll update the answer...

Comment: Sorry, I read your statement as 'and', and didn't notice the arrangement that needs forwards L.